# Как правильно организовать архитектуру Wep Api?

Tags: c#, .net

Как правильно организовать архитектуру *Wep Api*?

Пример: есть контроллер `students`, в котором get-метод возвращает студента по id в бд. Если мне нужно получить студентов только с 1 группы, мне нужно создавать новый контроллер `studentSelectByGroupe` c одним методом? А потом мне нужно выбрать только с одного отделения, опять новый контроллер?

Получается, при большом приложении построенным на *Api*, нужно плодить очень много файлов-контроллеров? Или все-же можно нарушать *REST* и делать в одном контролере много разных методов? Но при этом же, как я понимаю, нарушается солид?

Как правильно построить *Api*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас должен быть один `Controller`, где вы описываете необходимые методы именно этого контролла.

К примеру, работаем со студентами. У нас есть общий `Controller` под студентов `StudentsController` (к прмеру). В нем мы реализовываем то, что будет связано со студентами (удаление, добавление, получение и так далее). :

```
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    //.....

    // GET: api/Students
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable GetStudents()
    {
        return Context.Students.Take(15);
    }

    // GET: api/Students/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStudent([FromRoute] string id)
    {
        var filtersModel = await Context.Students.Where(s => s.Group == id);
        return Ok(filtersModel);
    }

    //...
}
```

Вот к примеру (писал на коленке, за работоспособность не отвечаю, но саму суть уловите), у нас есть один `Controller` и с помощью него мы получаем по ссылке `сайт.рр/api/Students` список 15-ти студентов, а если в запрос добавим ещё и id студента (`сайт.рр/api/Students/petrov33`), то мы получаем объект нужного нам студента.

То есть `Controller` это у вас именно `сайт.рр/api/**Students**` в адресе и методы внутри должны быть все связаны с этим `Controller`. Не стоит писать в `Controller` студентов логику вывода бухгалтерии или книг, ведь не логично, если вы будете писать `сайт.рр/api/Students/книги/Война_и_Мир` (если только конечно книги, это не книги самого студента, тогда да..)

Comment: А если нам нужно отобрать студентов с 1 группы? А потом еще с одного отделения? При этом нужно оставить выбор по айди самого студента.

Comment: Вы работаете с чем? Со студентами или с отделениями? Если со студентами - логика к контролу студентов. Если с отделениями, то это логика контрола отделений.

Comment: Это понятно, но если нужно отобрать с бд именно студнтов с одного отделения, чтоб не отправлять кучу данных на клиент и там делать отбор? Нужно создавать новый контроллер для этого?

Comment: Мне кажется вам не понятно... Вы же сами себе противоречите. У вас есть контрол студентов, адрес этого контрола `/api/students` (к примеру). Вы говорите "надо получить студентов с одного отделения". Кого вы отбирать собрались? Студентов ведь, а не отделения. Значит у вас в контроле студентов должен быть соответствующий метод, который к примеру будет вызываться так: `/api/STUDENTS/GetByGroup/groupName`. Зачем вам для этого создавать отдельный контрол?

Comment: Именно это я и хотел услышать. Но ведь по Rest  маршрут не может содержать GetByGroupe. В одном контроллере не может же  быть много методов get с одинковой сигнатурой.

Comment: Ну я не знаю по каким вы принципам пишите. Я лично работал с `.Net Core` и переписывал его стандартный контрол на api. А в его примерах там как минимум 2 GET. Что мешает добавить ещё? Вот кстати можно посмотреть [стандартную развертку у .NET Core](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.1.php). А маршруты все настраиваются легко.

Comment: Там 2 GET с разной сигнатурой, А если сигнатура одинаковая, нужно писать в маршрут имя метода. Но на всех уроках говориться, что нужно писать в маршрут только имя контроллера.

Comment: Я понимаю, что можно сделать как угодно, мой вопрос в ток, как правильно это делать так, чтоб мой API без проблем мог использовать фронтендщик. Есть же стандарты?

Comment: Я вам уже сказал как правильно. Для студентов своя логика в одном контроле, для книг свой контрол и все по своим контролам. Если вам надо из контрола вызвать нужный метод, то ему грамотно будет, указать свой путь, как указывается на [офф сайте](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: То есть вот [официальная документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) Вы указываете `[HttpGet("[controller]/[action]/{id}")] ` на метод `GetByGroup` и без проблем используете любое кол-во логики. Честно, я первый раз слышу, что бы в API был только 1 Get. Пропадает тогда вся его суть. Может я чего не знаю, но все ресурсы, где я разбирался по API говорили именно так. Да даже на любой API если глянуть, там у одного контрола куча методов. Возьмите к примеру [API VK](https://vk.com/dev/methods).

Comment: Тогда в маршруте должен писаться action.  Я же думал, что в Api не положено писать action в маршруте. Да и на всех туториалах, что я читал, говориться, что контроллер сам определяет каким action обработать запрос. И VS сама создает такой контроллер с [Route("api/.....")] без [action]. Спасибо вам, теперь я кажется понял.

Comment: @ДенисЧернов Ну, рад что разобрались ;-) p.s. Если ответ вас устраивает, то не забудьте отметить его "галкой" сбоку.